# Ajax / Query Current Users MySite for Data?

Tags: 2013

I'm looking to return a json or other such file with all the fields that I can see from the current user who is visiting the site. For example, query their MySite for their following list or social feed. Am I missing a webpart that is already included to do this or can I use jquery/ajax to pull a clean list I can style from a certain url?

I don't have collection admin, just access to run scripts via the site I own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST endpoints available under `SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager`

For current user the URL will be like

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

You can then select the list of properties you want using `select`

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl,AccountName
```

Check [this](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html) blog to find out how to invoke and the list of available properties you can query.

Comment: Thanks Amal. I get this huge XML list which is great. However, I do not see anything related to where users have last been visiting. Is this info not kept in the MySite info?

Comment: AH, a good example would be mysite/Social/Sites.aspx How do I get that list?